# Do newly designed amateur video cameras still shoot interlaced footage by default?

Tags: video-recording

I have a relatively cheap video camera (one of the Sony HandyCam models). Even when the model is recent, I think it is essentially a variation of a hardware that has been around for some time. It shoots 59.94 interlaced fields per second by default (though it has also progressive 29.97 and 59.94 modes).

I don't know if the interlaced mode is there because of legacy reasons, or if it is really used and appreciated by amateurs. I see a lot of people taking progressive videos, specially with machines that resemble a traditional reflex camera instead of a video camera and apparently do not include an interlaced mode.

I like interlacing, though that is not the question because I can see a lot of discussing around this preference all over the internet. My question is, are the other manufacturers of newly designed camcorders still including interlacing modes by default in non-professional cameras like my HandyCam, or is it a format that is about to disappear from amateur machines? Is there any standard regulating this?

Comment: Since all consumer HD displays handle interlaced video by buffering and deinterlacing it before display, I think the days of interlacing are numbered. Rather than being a deliberate decision, it has the appearance of a disconnect between the broadcast standards committees and the rest of industry

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at [Bluray video codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray#Video), you'll see that the 50+ fps HD formats at 1080 row resolution are all defined as interlaced formats.

That's a strong incentive for 1080 line interlaced formats not to go away fast in consumer grade cameras.